# Open close div on change of radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am doing http://jsfiddle.net/7VBJn/2/ method to do this.

It works fine but i want first div to be open always. I am facing problems doing this.

Please help me.

Code extract:

```
var current = '';
$('[name="week_day_time"]').change(function() {
    if(current.length) 
        $('#' + current).slideUp();
    current = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: first div is <div id="week">?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want. What do you mean by "open always"? Do you mean open at start or something else :)

Comment: You're using what method to do what? Please show your relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code here in your question.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, i was unable to add the fiddle link. now it's fine.

Comment: They meant add the code here :) I have done that for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/7VBJn/197/ like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the first element `change` event via code using `trigger` or `change` (so that a specified item starts open, without contriving visible states and styling):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7VBJn/199/

You can also simplify the selection code using `not` (you do not need the current global variable). This just requires a common class on the `info` divs:

```
$('[name="week_day_time"]').change(function () {
    var $current = $('#' + $(this).val());
    $('.info').not($current).slideUp();
    $current.slideDown();
}).filter('[value=week]').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('[name="week_day_time"]').change(function () {
    var $current = $('#' + $(this).val());
    $('.info').not($current).slideUp();
    $current.slideDown();
}).filter('[value=week]').change();
```

Comment: If you use `change()`, without passing a function, it serves as an alias to `trigger('change');` (and negligibly reduces typing too!).

Comment: @David Thomas: true. I tend to use `trigger` explicitly as I do a lot of custom event generation (probably more than I should). Updated to show both :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set week as the current for the first time:

Set week input as checked:

```
<input type="radio" name="week_day_time" value="week" checked />Week<br />
```

Initialize current as `week`:

```
var current = 'week';
```

Do not hide `week`:

```
#day, #time {
    display: none;
}
```

See code working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7VBJn/200/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to open the div `#week` by default, just remove it from the CSS selector to which you apply `display: none` and set `current` to `"week"` initially.

```
/* Instead of #week, #day, #time */
#day, #time {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7VBJn/201/

I also set the radio button for week to `checked` to reflect that change in the form as well.

Comment: i tried this, but when i click another radio button first div is not closed. that's the problem.

Comment: You're right. If you set the `current` to `"week"´ to reflect that as well, it works. I updated the answer.